# XAMPP phpMyAdmin - different users access same MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, localhost, xampp

I have created a MySQL database on MyPHPAdmin (XAMPP 3.2). This is for a group project and I need to have different users access the same database.

If they have XAMPP installed on their computer, is this possible to be done?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about webmastering. Sorry.